# Angular production observables dont change

Tags: angular, http, observable, detection, production-environment

i have an app on production on a server and i have this problems. the api is bringing the data correctly but the component is not detecting when the data comes, so is not updating the view.

this is the code of the components method:

```
private loadRecetas = () => {
    this.data = [];
    this.loaderService.showLoader();
    this.itemRecetasService.getItemRecetas().subscribe((success: any) => {
        this.data = success.data;
        this.loaderService.hideLoader();
    }, error => {
        this.snackbarService.errorSnackBar('Ocurrio un error al cargar las recetas');
        this.loaderService.hideLoader();
    });
};
```

and here is to code of the service

```
public getItemRecetas = () => {
        const url = this.buildUrl(this.itemsRecetasUrl);
        return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.getHeaders()});
    };
```

I have worked with angular before and this is the first time that this happens to me.

i will appreciate the comments.

UPDATE:
i did some console in my component and this is what happens.
i have a child component that receives the data from the parent. it does pass the data the first time (an empty array) but it never updates after that.

Comment: Is the change detection strategy set to OnPush() ?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on `this.data = success.data`, and does it get hit?

Comment: Try running your app in production mode locally with the commando: ng serve --prod. It's slower because it builds everything like it would for prod, but at least you could try debugging that way.

Comment: Hi, did you check your network tab in page console ? Do you see if your request is sent properly ?Are you sure CORS are set correctly ? Did you try to console.log success ?

Comment: @FranklinPious no, i have the default detection.

Comment: @theMayer what do you mean with a breakpoint ? i dont understand that.

Comment: @millenion yes, the service returns the dara correctly. i can see it in the developer tools. but in the app does not update. i run the deploy app on my local and it behaves the same.

Comment: I think you might want to read a tutorial on debugging.